# Есть ли смысл помещать запрос в БД select в цикл?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

Посоветуйте, что делать, если я сделал запрос в базу, но не получил значения, при условии что оно там точно есть, я не знаю какие сбои бывают при работе с БД, есть ли смысл сделать повторное обращение, через repeat например 5 раз, а если ответа все равно нет то завершать работу с ошибкой?
Вот так я делаю запроссы

```
class function RGetInfo.GetLoginUser(LoginUser: TLoginUser): Boolean;
var
  FDConnection: TFDConnection;
  FDQuery: TFDQuery;
begin
  FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    with FDConnection do
    begin
      Params.Add('Database=mybd');
      Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
      Params.Add('Password=123456');
      Params.Add('Server=localhost');
      Params.Add('User_Name=root');
      Params.Add('CharacterSet=utf8');
      Params.Add('ReadTimeout=100');
      Connected := True;
    end;
    FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      FDQuery.Connection := FDConnection;
      try
        FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
        FDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `uplayers` WHERE `name` = "' + LoginUser.Name + '" LIMIT 1');
        FDQuery.Open;
          LoginUser.pType           := FDQuery.FieldByName('type').AsString;
          LoginUser.Pass            := FDQuery.FieldByName('pass').AsString;
          LoginUser.PassType        := FDQuery.FieldByName('passtype').AsString;
          LoginUser.Active          := FDQuery.FieldByName('active').AsBoolean;
          LoginUser.Oper.Name       := FDQuery.FieldByName('oper').AsString;
          LoginUser.Admin.Name      := FDQuery.FieldByName('admin').AsString;
          LoginUser.SuperAdmin.Name := FDQuery.FieldByName('superadmin').AsString;
        FDQuery.Close;
      finally
        Result := True;
      end;
    finally
      FDQuery.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FDConnection.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А вы не хотите привести пример того что вы делаете, с примером того какие поля есть в базе?

Comment: @Shnur добавил в вопрос

Comment: Возможно есть смысл перед запросом начать новую транзакцию..

Comment: @vp_arth то есть?

Comment: Если вы используете механизм транзакций, то есть вероятность, что на момент создания текущей данных в базе не было. Тогда, разумеется, запрос ничего не вернёт. Нужно завершить текущую транзакцию и начать новую. (Полагаю, первое если в этом комментарии вернёт ложь :) )

Comment: Что это за код у вас в вопросе? Delphi? Добавьте тег

Comment: @vp_arth да Delphi, а что за тег?

Comment: *я сделал запрос в базу, но не получил значения, при условии что оно там точно есть* Ну первое, что надо сделать - это посмотреть FDConnection и FDQuery на предмет статуса и ошибок. А то Ваше желание сделать 5 repeat-ов сродни `for(i=1,i<5,i++) {x=2?x:2;}`

Comment: Если запрос в БД отработал без ошибок и БД не вернула значение - значит его там нет, что бы это не значило

Comment: зачем каждый раз коннект создавать? создайте один коннект, и через него ходите.

Comment: @teran я позже так и сделаю, на поток 1 connection, в TPlayer-а добавлю)

Comment: Akina и Mike, спасибо, буду читать об ошибках которые могу возвращать sql запросы

Comment: на заре изучения делфи я так пытался отловить ошибку. В одном месте данные добавлял/редактировал, а в другом использовал. И во втором все никак измененные данные получить не мог, оказалось что запросы через разные коннекты к базе подключались.

Comment: @teran у меня сейчас, поток при вызове, любой функции, для работы с БД,создает соединение, читает\пишет, уникальные для каждого потока строки, закрывает соединение, с одного потока думаю не получится прочесть неактуальные данные, в случаях где строки не уникальны читать и сразу изменять буду как сказал Mike, в другой теме. А вообще, я с такой проблемой не сталкивался, просто хочу как то обработать ошибки при чтении из базы, но так легко, как хотел (если с первого раза не получилось попробовать еще несколько раз) не получится)

Comment: любая ошибка работы с базой выпадет вам с эксепшеном. Пробовать читать по несокльку раз, это тоже не корректное решение

Comment: Если запрос не может выполнится из за ошибки - используйте блок `try... except...end` для корректной обработки ошибки. И в случае необходимости - повторяйте попытку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как показывает практика, в подобных случаях чаще всего проблема в самом запросе. И repeat'ы тут не помогут.
Я бы посмотрел, значение FDQuery.SQL.Text и вставил бы его в какой-нибудь SQL редактор, типа phpMyAdmin.
А на вскидку, проблема может быть в кавычках.
Попробуйте вместо
SELECT * FROM `uplayers` WHERE `name`
написать
SELECT * FROM [uplayers] WHERE [name]

или просто 
SELECT * FROM uplayers WHERE name